# How to declare a List of Bytes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working in a project wherein I want to use a byte type for a variable.
But when I try `byte varName` or `List<byte> varName`, the keyword `byte` is underlined. 
I want to do a thing like that

> `List<byte> varName = [0, 2, 5 ,7, ..., ..., x];`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not looking for a `List<int>`, check the [docs](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/List-class.html) for `List` in dart.

Comment: see `ByteBuffer` and `ByteData`

Comment: Great! Thanks @EnzoLizama. I never used `ByteBuffer` but I will try them. Thanks @pskink

Comment: You really don't need to do List<byte>, but Uint8List, which is the equivalent of a Java List<byte>. See my answer below...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a `Uint8List`, not a `List<byte>` or `List<int>`.

Think about it: There's 8 bits in one byte. Therefore, a Java List is storing 8 bits in each item. In the same way, a Uint8List stores 8 bits per item, or one byte per item.

The way that you would do this using the provided code:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data'; //Bundled with Dart

Uint8List example = Uint8List.fromList([0, 2, 5 ,7, ..., ..., x]); //Uint8List of bytes
```

You could also *technically* use `List<int>`, but then bitwise operations become more tricky, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: `Uint8List` is a `List<int>` because it extends it. You could have also mentioned `Int8List` (see my answer).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot You're right about Int8List. Just because Uint8List is a List<int> doesn't mean there's no difference between the 2.

Answer (score 3):

A byte is just a number between 0 and 255, so it's fine to declare a list of bytes like so:

```dart
List<int> byteList = [0, 2, 5, 7, 42, 255];
```

However, the `int` type holds 64-bit values, so it's a little overkill for 8-bit values. For small lists it doesn't matter, but for large lists the `Uint8List` type better for the job:

```dart
// import 'dart:typed_data';

Uint8List byteList = Uint8List.fromList([0, 2, 5, 7, 42, 255]);
```

`Uint8List` is fixed size and holds unsigned 8-bit values.

Answer (score 1):

In Dart, bytes are simply stored as `int`s. If you want to use lists of specific int sizes, you can make use of [`dart:typed_data`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html).
In your case, that would be either [`Uint8List`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html) (for unsigned integers of 8 bits) or [`Int8List`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-typed_data/Int8List-class.html) (for signed integers of 8 bits).

Comment: Thanks. I think this will help.